# Fantasy novel series; one of the books has a general with eagle-like features on the cover

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a series of fantasy novels I read in the '90s. One of them had the following cover featuring a general with eagle-like features, who was one of the main characters.

<sub>Note that the image below is a *tracing* of the cover.</sub>
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. We could really use some more info to help us identify this series. Please [edit] your question to describe the plot and any prominent characters, in as much detail as you can recall.

Comment: Hi @LogicDictates, I hoped that I recalled more. I stumbled upon the image, which I traced at the time from the cover, and that gave me some hope of finding it.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176844.The_Eagle_the_Nightingales?

Comment: looks like it could be [Enki Bilal](https://www.google.com/search?q=enki+bilal+eagle&source=lnms&tbm=isch&biw=1622&bih=848) work.  Did the guy have Soviet/Eastern Bloc look too?  Or something based on Egyptian goods?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think this is ["El Devastador"](https://www.alibrate.com/libro/el-devastador-el-reino-de-los-dragones-3-/5bb8f1badd3f9662a9276001), book 3 of the series "El Reino de los Dragones" by "Richard A. Knaak". The cover image matches the tracing both in general pose and down to details such as the three-fingered hand with one slightly bent finger.

The original title of the book (which features different cover art) appears to be ["Wolfhelm"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/279580.Wolfhelm), from the (first) "Dragonrealm" series.

### [image]

After having no success with many combinations of related terms in English (e.g. general/major/character/...; eagle/buzzard/hawk/falcon/...), I decided to broaden my search into other languages. Eventually, googling for

> libro fantasia aguila general

brought up a cover image of this book.

Comment: Well done!  ISFDb doesn't have the best coverage of translations, but that art is [noted as used](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1981837) for a 2014 omnibus of the first three books.

Comment: You have to admit the spanish title is MUCH better than the original.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can come to that particular image is the 1995 Baen imprint of *The Eagle & the Nightingales* by Mercedes Lackey, as seen [here](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176844.The_Eagle_the_Nightingales):

[image: cover showing an eagle general]

It's the 5th book in a series, but the bird seems to be lacking enough clothing for it to be the right pick, might be worth a look regardless.

Comment: I did consider posting this as an answer (rather than a comment) but I couldn't find a relevant book cover, noting that OP *traced* it from the original. This one comes closest, but it's not the same; https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1178878474l/848558.jpg

Comment: Also, the birdman character in that book is not a general, but an ambassador / bard.